# Recording free items in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, erp

In Netsuite, how is the practice of including a free item done? Let's say there will be a free item A for a sales order which exceeds $1000. How do you record this in the system?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways. One is just to add the free item with a price level of "Free". The item can be added via script, or by a person like the approver or fulfiller.

For managing the free item price you can also create a 100% discount coupon code that would be applied to the free item when it is added to an order over $1000.